# Python: How to add two large masked arrays and keep their values (i.e. mask + value = value)?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, addition, mask

I want to combine two masked array in such way that

```
array_one      = [1,    mask,   mask]

array_two      = [mask, 2,      mask]

combined_array = [1,    2,      mask]
```

Note that I have huge 2-D arrays!

Code:

#### Mask

```
SO  = np.ma.masked_where(tmask != 1, tmask)

SO[:,0:x] = np.ma.masked

SO[:,y:-1] = np.ma.masked
```

#### Mask for the Atlantic

```
Atl  = np.ma.masked_where(tmask != 2, tmask)

Atl  = Atl/Atl  # To have a value of 1

SO = np.ma.add(Atl,SO) ### This give mask + value = mask
```

I also tried something like

```
Atl = set(Atl)

SO = set.union(Atl,SO)
```

Comment: Please share your code, and specify what part of your code isnt working.

Comment: Please edit the question rather than posting unformulated code as a comment

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
combined_array = list(set(array_one+array_two))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
array_one = [1, None, None, 3]
array_two = [None, 2, None, 4]


def combine(primary_array, secondary_array):
    """
    Arrays must be of equal length, primary overwrites secondary
    :param primary_array: [1, None, None, 3]
    :param secondary_array: [None, 2, None, 4]
    :return: [1, 2, None, 3]
    """
    result = []
    for x, y in zip(primary_array, secondary_array):
        if x is None and y is None:
            result.append(None)
        elif isinstance(x, (int, float)):
            result.append(x)
        elif isinstance(y, (int, float)):
            result.append(y)
        else:
            # Ignore if both x and y != int or float
            pass
    return result


print(combine(array_one, array_two))
```